# hql select from select problem

Tags: sql, hibernate, count, hql

I would like to count the number of groups of a group by statement. 
In SQL that would look like:

```
select count(*) from (select count(*) from MyTable t group by t.col1, t.col2) g
```

But in HQL it seems I can not do a select in a select as I did in the previous sql. I guess the problem is that `Hibernate` does not support subquery in the `from` clause.
Is there any way to do this in `hql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have finally run the following query in hql:

```
select count(*) from MyTable t group by t.col1, t.col2
```

and then used the size of the returned list, which is exactly the number of groups.